# conditional based on month

Tags: php

I'm looking to create an if/else statement that first checks to see if the current month is >= January and <= July (basically any month from Jan-July.  If it is, display code snippet a.  If not, than show code snippet b.  I'm just learning PHP, and I haven't had any luck on google.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The date() function is really helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
if(date("m") >= 1 && date("m") <= 7){
    //display snippet a
} else {
    //display snippet b
}
```

if you're going to be doing anything with dates, also look at strtotime(), really useful for turning one format into another.

Edit: use and, not or.

Comment: strtotime is handy, but not reliable. better off to use the DateTime library instead.

Answer (score 0):

`date("m")` returns a numeric representation of the month. So you can test it against conditionals like:

```
if ((date("m")  >0) && (date("m") <= 7)) {

}
```